# Weights of features in k-means

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, k-means

I have a set of wikipedia texts that I want to cluster.

The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd                                             
import numpy as np                                             
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

#parameters
maximum_features = 1000000
max_intera = 300

#load text file
wiki = pd.read_csv('people_wiki.csv')

#TF-IDF vectorization
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=maximum_features, norm = 'l2', stop_words='english')
tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(wiki['text'])

#clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0, init='k-means++', max_iter = max_intera).fit(tfidf)
```

I want to know the weight of each feature, like shown here (she 0.025 her: 0.017 .....):

[image]

In summary: I want the weights of each feature (word) and present the 5 more relevant.

The file 'people_wiki.csv' is here:

https://ufile.io/udg1y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this solution:

```
print(tfidf.idf_)
```